# Click button without ID using VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, automation, onclick

I want to download historic data from NASDAQ using VBA. I have managed to change the "FromDate" to the proper range but I haven't managed to get the code to hit the "Search" button (as it has no ID) which extracts the data. Please help me out.

**MY VBA:**

```
Sub OMX_data()

Dim URL As String
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate ("http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/indexes/historical_prices?Instrument=DK0060368991")

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4

ie.document.all("FromDate").Value = "2018-01-01"

End Sub
```

**THE HTML**

```html
<div class="filterAreaRow overflowHidden">
<div class="button doSearch floatRight ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="historical.load();return false;" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Search</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get search button element by class using `getElementsByClassName` and can trig it by `Click` method, `doSearch` is the name of search button in this form.

The last two line is the solution of your question.

```
Sub OMX_data()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate ("http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/indexes/historical_prices?Instrument=DK0060368991")

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = 4

    ie.Document.all("FromDate").Value = "2018-01-01"

    Set search_button = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("doSearch")
    search_button(0).Click
End Sub
```

You can use HTML DOM to import data to Excel,
Below is example to import data to Excel

```
Sub OMX_data()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.Navigate ("http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/indexes/historical_prices?Instrument=DK0060368991")

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4

    ie.Document.all("FromDate").Value = "2018-01-01"

    Set search_button = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("doSearch")
    search_button(0).Click

    ' Wait for filter apply
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    ' Use HTML DOM
    Set result = ie.Document.getElementById("historicalOutput").getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

    i = 0   ' for row
    For Each r In result
        j = 0   ' for column
        For Each c In r.Children
            Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value = c.innertext
            j = j + 1
            DoEvents
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Next

    MsgBox "Import finish"
End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic! It works. Can you also help with me getting the data to excel or should that be in a different question? 

<table id="historicalTable" class="tablesorter tablesorter-default" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="grid">